# WSO2 ESB REST API - Dynamic HTTP EndPoint (using Template Endpoint) Externalise - Hostname and port number

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I want to externalize the hostname and port number in HTTP endpoint, so I am trying to pass the hostname and port number in JVM argument while starting the ESB.
 Using script/class mediator, I can get it from system properties and put it in message context. Then using property mediator, I can access and log the value of it.
 Till this point, I don't have any issue but when I try to use this value to replace in the HTTP endpoint as below; it doesn't work.

Actual ESB Synapse API Config:

---

```
 <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ContentLength" context="/content">
    <resource methods="GET">
       <inSequence>
          <send>
             <endpoint>
               <http method="get" uri-template="http://198.160.1.223:8080/greeting/{uri.var.name}"></http>
             </endpoint>
          </send>
       </inSequence>
       <outSequence>
          <send></send>
       </outSequence>
   </resource>
 </api>
```

Expected ESB Synapse API Config:

---

```
  <api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ContentLength" context="/content">
     <resource methods="GET">
        <inSequence>
            <script language="js">mc.setProperty("system.hostname",java.lang.System.getProperty("my.hostname"));mc.setProperty("system.port.no",java.lang.System.getProperty("my.port.no"));</script>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="system.hostname" expression="get-property('system.hostname')"/>
           <property name="system.port.no" expression="get-property('system.port.no')"/>
        </log>
            <send>
              <endpoint>
                <http method="get" uri-template="http://{system.prop.my.hostname}:{system.prop.my.port.no}/greeting/{uri.var.name}"></http>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
           <send></send>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
  </api>
```

Is there any way I can use Template Endpoint and HTTP endpoint in this scenario ?

Let me know alternative options as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<property name="uri.var.host" expression="get-property('system.hostname')"/>
       <property name="uri.var.port" expression="get-property('system.port.no')"/>
    </log>
        <send>
          <endpoint>
            <http method="get" uri-template="http://{uri.var.host}:{uri.var.port}/greeting/{uri.var.name}"></http>
          </endpoint>
       </send>
```

Change as above. It will work.

Comment: thanks Ragavan. It worked. I missed the point uri template variable has to start with uri.var.  [The HTTP endpoint allows you to define REST endpoints using URI templates similar to the REST API. The URI templates allow a RESTful URI to contain variables that can be populated during mediation runtime using property values whose names have the "uri.var." prefix. An HTTP endpoint can also define the particular HTTP method to use in the RESTful invocation.]

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked for alternative options you can do string concatenation at the property mediator for hostname and port and then directly use it in the uri-template.

Please refer [this link](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/HTTP+Endpoint) to get an idea about http endpoints.