# How to retrieve wso2 server running port number using property mediator

Tags: wso2

I tried following `<property expression="get-property('system.port.no')" name="system.port.no"/>`giving null value.
for IP address i am able to get by using "SERVER_IP" default parameter

Is there any default parameter to get running wso2 server port number?

Comment: where do you get "system.port.no" ???

Comment: In stack over flow "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074581/wso2-esb-rest-api-dynamic-http-endpoint-using-template-endpoint-externalise" But i realized it is not the wso2 default constants.

Comment: In the post it is claimed ".. trying to pass the hostname and port number in JVM argument .. get it from system properties" so in this case the "system.port.no" seems to be passed as a system property (when running wso2server script)

Comment: Ok, Thank you. Do mean to say there is no way to retrieve from synapses constants?